# Getting HTTP Status 503 on glassfish after deployment

Tags: jsf, deployment, glassfish

Here's the scanario... i have a glassfish server runnung my app on EC2, i configured a virtual server on glassfish for one of my domains (lets say mydomain.com) and this same virtual server has a default web module (lets say "myapp").

it works like a charm, when i access www.mydomain.com i get the login screen for my app, as it should be... no need to access www.mydomain.com/myapp (/myapp is the default context path for myapp).

But here's the thing; after i do a new deployment of my WAR file i can't access my app. if i type www.mydomain.com on the browser and press ENTER, the server gives me an "HTTP Status 503" however, if a access www.mydomain.com/myapp y can see my login page.

this problem goes away after i do a "sudo service glassfish restart" but as you might think, restarting the app server after every deployment is a pain, and btw, this is not the only app i'm running here, so... restarting glassfish just shuts down all apps and pisses off all users.

I'm deploying from Netbeans but i get the same result deploying from command line (asadmin).

i tried google but the notes i found didn't help.

is this a glassfish config problem? 
am i missing a step after deployment?

for reference, i'm using: jsf 2.1, primefaces 3.2, jasper reports 4.6 (with required dependencies), mysql connector, glassfish server ose 3.1.2.2

i'll appreciate any help.

thanks.

Comment: Are there errors in the server log?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like Im shooting in the dark but here it goes.

In most cases, HTTP Error 503: Service Unavailable indicates that the App Server / Tomcat Server was not communicating well with the Web server, normally Apache.

Whats interesting is that when you sudo restart, it works, ITs a good indication of permissions of the filesystems. If you have deployed as a normal user but you have set up the server as root, this might just be the problem.

Yes, its a config problem & more. Try checking the file permissions & assign users to each process & make them play well.

Let me know if you could share some errors / logs, it would be helpful.

Comment: i did the setup with "sudo", also created the startup script with sudo... does that mean the processes are running as root??? (i'm not sure). about the logs... if i "empty" the log while myapp is running fine, then redeploy and start getting the http error 503, there's nothing in the log about it, the log only has a few lines about the deployment, no error's or warnings. i'm checking only the domain log, is there any other log file i'm not aware of???  tnx!

Comment: Could you confirm the User that starts or deploys the WebApp is the same as the user you use to SuDo (Root) , if its different, then its 99% the chance of file permissions. Best to get these data from a startup Servlet or a JSP. Encountered this problem too many times with Tomcat and Apache. But this tool may help, I wrote this to help maintain the servers (http://code.google.com/p/apachecat/), You could use some scripts to safely start or stop the servers as an option